# Short Story. Humans land on Mars. Communicate with martians by drawing pictures. Miscommunication gets humans killed

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, mars

They communicate with the martians by drawing pictures. At first it seems to be going well. The human draws a right angled triangle labelled two sides III and IIII. The martian labelled the hypotenuse IIIII.

Then the human draws the sun and planets. Tries to communicate that they are from the 3rd planet, the martians from the fourth.

Mercury cannot be seen from Mars. Martians think they live on third planet. They understand the drawing to mean humans intend to take Mars and drive them away to Jupiter, so they kill them.

I read it within the last ten years but I think it was several decades old. I read it online

Comment: When did you read this? Was it in a magazine, an anthology book, online?

Comment: I read it within the last ten years but I think it was several decades old. I read it online.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Communication](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?92970) by Charles L. Fontenay. It was published in 1956 so it is indeed an old story. It can be read on the [Project Gutenberg web site](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/59556).

> THE first terrestrial expedition to Mars didn’t find any Martians. Neither did the second. Since there are so few Martians left, those facts are less surprising than that the third did.
>
> For many years before space flight was accomplished, there had been discussions and theories about how to communicate with Martians, if any existed. But, of course, nobody was ready when the time came.

The scene with the triangle is:

> While his companions watched curiously, he shut his ears to the running fire of questions from Powers, squatted and drew a right angled triangle in the red desert sand. By one of the sides he drew three marks, by another four.
>
> Then he stepped back and looked questioningly at the Martians.
>
> One of the Martians squatted in a tangle of pipestem arms and legs, and with a long finger drew five lines beside the triangle’s hypotenuse.

Then:

> He pointed to the third planet, then at himself, then at his companions, one by one. Then he pointed at the fourth planet and at the Martians, one by one. To complete the matter, he pointed at the sky.
>
> “We are Earthmen,” he said. “You are Martians.”
>
> The trouble was that the Earth-men didn’t realize the things the Martians had were weapons until they used them. They didn’t realize it then, as a matter of fact, because the Earthmen were dead, all three of them.

It ends with the remaining crew members wondering where the others are:

> Biggs and Golden were working near the G-boat. Their helmet radios were set to a different channel from that used by the exploring party, so they were unable to hear Captain Powers shouting frantically into his microphone and getting no answer. It was just after sunset, and Biggs was looking into the west.
>
> “We ought to see it now, but it ain’t there,” commented Biggs.
>
> “What ain’t there?” demanded Golden.
>
> “Mercury,” said Biggs, who prided himself on being an amateur astronomer. “I reckon you can’t see it from Mars without a telescope. Too close to the sun.” He chuckled.
>
> “If there are any Martians,” he added, “I reckon they think they live on the third planet. That’s funny, ain’t it?”